# Finding the volume by the shell method

Tags: calculus, volume

Find the volume of the region generated by an area bounded between $y=x+6$ and $y=x^2$ rotated about the x-axis.

So the formula of the shell method is $\int_{a}^{b}2\pi rhdx$, but in this case the integral is in terms of $y$. I solved the two equations in terms of $y$ and got $x=y-6$ and $x=\sqrt{y}$. The height of the shell is $\sqrt{y}-(y-6)$ which equals $\sqrt{y}-y+6$ and the radius should be $y$. The points of intersection between these two equations are $(-2,4)$ and $(3,9)$.

After plugging in all these values into the equation I ended up with a volume of $972\pi / 5$ but this isn't the correct volume. The homework said that I had to use the sum of two integrals but I'm not sure why. I looked on the graph I drew and saw that the region is in both the first and second quadrant. Other problems I did only had a region in the first quadrant. What did they mean when they said that I had to use the sum of two integrals? I am having a hard time picturing the shells in my head...

Comment: What you did is substracting the heights of both functions and integrating that. The solution in the book is (probably) found by integrating both function, and substracting the results.

Comment: I'm not sure how I would use the shell method if I integrated both functions separately then subtracting the results. Could someone explain?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason you need two integrals is because over the range $0$ to $4$ in $y$, the height of the shell is $2\sqrt y$ because it extends all the way across the $y$ axis.  Over the range $4$ to $9$ in $y$, the height is $\sqrt y -(y-6)$.  That changes the integrand, so split it into two integrals.

A sketch is below.  The horizontal lines are what are revolved to make the shells.  Note that the lower one extends from one side of the parabola to the other.  The upper one extends from the line to the parabola.  That is why the integral changes

[image]

Comment: I am having a hard time visualizing this. Is there an example of a similar problem with pictures?

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and picture!